# SIGSEGV from Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

I am having a linked list of nodes modified(added and deleted) dynamically from a user space program. What are the chances that the allocation of nodes are always in user space?

Usual Linked list node,

```
struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};
```

I got this question since when I traverse through the list, the kernel sends a `SIGSEGV` signal to this user space process.Also I have done the NULL pointer check whenever I create a new node.

Also I know that the kernel sends `SIGSEGV` signal if the process tries accessing kernel memory.

Comment: You're doing something wrong, otherwise you wouldn't be getting the SIGSEGV.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that I am trying to access an address of kernel?

Comment: Or something simply not mapped.

Comment: @cnicutar Thanks for your reply. If so, How can I fix it from a user space C programmer perspective. I mean I can not control the mapping of the allocated pointer.

Comment: I have briefed the question from a large embedded project, list traversed at various parts of the code. But the question is what is all about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16415/discussion-between-sibi-and-cnicutar)

Comment: SIGSEGV = segmentation fault = trying to access forbidden memory.

Comment: @Lundin, But why is this a forbidden memory. Do you mean that the memory is out of the process privilege. and if so why such a memory is allocated.

Comment: @Sibi Because you can address any memory of a computer, or at least any memory inside the virtual memory range visible to the program. Try to run this program: `*(int*)0 = 0;` and you'll get the same error. As for why it is allocated, who knows, there is a lot of things in the RAM of a computer. Perhaps that is where your program itself is running, for example.

Comment: You should learn to compile with all warning and debugging information (i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` on Linux), to use the debugger `gdb` and to use `valgrind`

Comment: And you understanding of `SIGSEGV` is not correct, you can get it as soon as you dereference an address out of your address space. Try to run `cat /proc/self/maps` to understand an address space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the chances that the allocation of nodes are always in user space?

100% certain.

> when I traverse through the list, the kernel sends a SIGSEGV signal

It means there is a bug in your program trying to access la-la-land.

> Also I know that the kernel sends SIGSEGV signal if the process tries accessing kernel memory.

SIGSEGV is a POSIX standard signal sent when the program tries to access forbidden memory. So not necessarily just kernel memory, but rather any memory anywhere outside the space that your process has access to.

Comment: Yes, all the allocation stays in user space. Kernel space is not directly visible from a user program.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks.Whatever address the process is trying to access, is it not going to in the range of 4 GB of virtual memory(say 32 bit) allocated for the process. And my understanding of virtual memory is that it is the combination of just kernel and process memory.

Comment: @Sibi No, [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) is something laying on top of the physical memory addresses, preventing you from doing crazy things like overwriting the memory of other processes (such as the kernel processes) but also restricting direct access to physical hardware registers. I don't know much about Linux specifically, but the virtual memory mapping is typically even closer to the hardware than the OS itself: The CPU provides ways to map virtual memory segments by writing to CPU hardware registers at boot up.

Comment: (So without being a x86/Linux/POSIX expert, I'm guessing SIGSEGV is really a hardware exception tossed deep down from the CPU memory mapping peripheral hardware, into the OS, which then adds some flavour on top of it and passes it on, in the form of a software signal. Maybe some x86 guru is willing to provide more detailed info of what is going on underneath the hood.)

Comment: @Lundin Thanks again. [From this image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Virtual_memory.svg) whatever address in the range 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF , its corresponding code or data is either available in either memory or disk. At the maximum, it can cause a page fault in case the process is referring to some virtual address from the disk. My doubt is where is the forbidden memory coming from?

Answer (score 2):

SIGSEGV is a segmentation fault. What this means is that your program is trying to access memory in a region that is not inside of the programs allotted memory range, or segment. Segmentation was an ugly system that people used to have to deal with directly, but not so much anymore. What it means for you today is that your code is most likely deferencing either a null pointer or some un-initialized value.

What you should do is hook your debugger up to your program and see what address is causing the SIGSEGV to be thrown. As soon as you see it, it will most likely be 0x0, or some garbage value such as 0xDEADC0DE or something.

Probably you are not setting all the pointers in your nodes to 0x0. Do this inside the constructor and double check your addNode() removeNode() function to be sure you don't have dangling pointers hanging around.

Comment: `SIGSEGV` has not much to do with the dreaded "x86 segmentation" of ages past; it's a signal that every UN*X OS, whether on x86 or any other architecture, will create for any attempt to access memory at an invalid address. _Invalid address_ in this case means no _MMU mapping_ exists, unlike the other possible case of a bad pointer where such a mapping exists but isn't accessible - that results in `SIGBUS` instead (try `mmap`'ing readonly and then writing to that mem). The "Segmentation Violation" name is merely historical coincidence.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to set next=NULL; in node constructor, or just after node creation.
And yes, allocation is always done in user space